# Prophet package in R : Unable to load from library

Tags: r, facebook

Can someone help me with "prophet" package addition to library?

I was successful in installing the package on R version 3.3.3 including the dependent files, however when I try using it "library (prophet)" - I get the following . I did look for solutions on the link provided in the error along with various other forums but found no solutions.

Does this package require C++ Compiler to be installed? How do I resolve this issue?

```
Warning: running command '"C:/Documents/R/R-3.3.3/bin//R" CMD config CXX' had status 1
No C++ compiler found, so the following will probably not work.
See https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Windows#toolchain
Warning: running command 'C:/Documents/R/R-3.3.3/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file54474622720.cpp 2> file54474622720.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' S

HLIB="file54474622720.dll" OBJECTS="file54474622720.o"' had status 127 

ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

Program source:
     1: 
    '2: // includes from the plugin
    '3: 
    '4: 
    '5: // user includes
    '6: #define STAN__SERVICES__COMMAND_HPP// Code generated by Stan version '2.15.0
    '7: 
    '8: #include <stan/model/model_header.hpp>
    '9: 
    '10: namespace model54441212ef0_prophet_linear_growth_namespace {
    '11: 
    '12: using std::istream;
    '13: using std::string;
    '14: using std::stringstream;
    '15: using std::vector;
    '.
    '.
    '.
    '663: // declarations
    '664: extern "C" {
    '665: SEXP file54474622720( ) ;
    '666: }
    '667: 
    '668: // definition
    '669: 
    '670: SEXP file54474622720(  ){
    '671:  return Rcpp::wrap("prophet_linear_growth");
    '672: }
    '673: 
    '674:

    'Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'prophet', details:
    'call: compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose)
    'error: Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warning message:
    'running command 'make -f "C:/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf"
    '"C:/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk"
    'SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD) 'SHLIB="file54474622720.dll" OBJECTS="file54474622720.o"' had status 127 
    'Error: package or namespace load failed for 'prophet'
```

Comment: Looks like you're on windows. If so, have you installed [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)?

Comment: That's right, I am on Windows and have Rtools too!

Comment: R-3.3.3 is installed in "C:\MyDocuments\" but RTools in on "C:\" (Different paths) will that cause an issue or is there a way to ensure Rtools is connected to the current session in use?